# UIButton with fixed size custom image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uibutton

I have a custom UIButton as follows:

```
 UIButton * action = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [action setSize:CGSizeMake(30, 30)];
    [action setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"contextaction.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [action setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
    [action addTarget:self action:@selector(actionButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The real image that I have is actually sized at 10x10, centered and I want it to stay that way and not scaled to the button size. How do I do that?

**REVISED CODE:**

```
UIButton * action = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [action setSize:CGSizeMake(44, 44)];
    [action setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"contextaction.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [action addTarget:self action:@selector(actionButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    if (IS_IPAD){
        action.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
        action.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    }
     actionButton_ = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:action];
```

which is still scaling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this i think you need to make use of the image insets property [UIButton Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/imageEdgeInsets)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `setImage:forState:` method of `UIButton` instead of `setBackgroundImage:forState:`

`UIButton` inherits from `UIControl`, so you can set the `contentHorizontalAlignment` and `contentVerticalAlignment` properties to `UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter` and `UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter`, respectively (although in most cases these are already the default values).

Comment: I have changed in using the setImage, how do I set the contentHorizontalAlignment

Comment: It is still scaling to the UIButton size

Answer (score 2):

Working example for Swift 3 hope it helps

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class MenuBtn: UIButton {

    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }

    func setupView(){
        imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        var image = imageView?.image
        image = image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

    }

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            tintColor = super.isSelected ? .gray : .gray
        }
    }

    override func imageRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let leftMargin:CGFloat = 40
        let imgWidth:CGFloat = 24
        let imgHeight:CGFloat = 24
        return CGRect(x: leftMargin, y: (contentRect.size.height-imgHeight) * 0.5, width: imgWidth, height: imgHeight)
    }

    override func titleRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let leftMargin:CGFloat = 80
        let rightMargin:CGFloat = 80
        return CGRect(x: leftMargin, y: 0, width: contentRect.size.width-leftMargin-rightMargin, height: contentRect.size.height)
    }

   override func backgroundRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
       let leftMargin:CGFloat = 10
       let rightMargin:CGFloat = 10
       let topMargin:CGFloat = 10
       let bottomMargin:CGFloat = 10
       return CGRect(x: leftMargin, y: topMargin, width: bounds.size.width-leftMargin-rightMargin, height: bounds.size.height-topMargin-bottomMargin)
    }


    override func contentRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let leftMargin:CGFloat = 5
        let rightMargin:CGFloat = 5
        let topMargin:CGFloat = 5
        let bottomMargin:CGFloat = 5
        return CGRect(x: leftMargin, y: topMargin, width: bounds.size.width-leftMargin-rightMargin, height: bounds.size.height-topMargin-bottomMargin)
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setupView()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be try something liky this...

```
 [button addSubview:imageView];
```

where imageView contains the image;

Answer (score 0):

use  setContentMode

```
[action setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
```

Answer (score 0):

Include QuartzCore framework and change gravity on the layer.

```
action.layer.contentsGravity=kCAGravityCenter;
```